# How to locate cells with different date format, then delete them in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have data with two different date formats (Fig.1), one format is "yyyy/m/d", the other is "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm".

I want to delete data whose date format is "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" (yellow in Fig.1), because I only need the daily data. The expected result is listed as below:

```
Date Collected  Value
2016/1/1    2.1
2016/1/2    0.6
2016/1/3    0.01
2016/1/4    0.9
2016/1/5    3
2016/1/6    1.9
2016/1/7    0.5
2016/1/8    1.1
2016/1/9    0
```

Could someone help me figure it out? The example can be downloaed in [here in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZLE678Gju50GmRHZODcFF5yGGdPhLQ5J)
[image: Fig1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, a date is a whole number, and the time is a decimal. You can subtract the `Int` of the cell from itself to see if the cell returns a value, if it does - then it contains a time. This is what you want to delete.

Add the data you want to delete to a special range, in this example: `delRng`, then delete `delRng` once you have finished looping.

```vb
Sub delData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim r As Long, delRng As Range
    With ws
        For r = 2 To LastRow(ws)
            If .Cells(r, 1) - Int(.Cells(r, 1)) > 0 Then
                If delRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set delRng = .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 2))
                Else
                    Set delRng = Union(delRng, .Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 2)))
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete

End Sub

Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Your idea to distinct them by "whether or not Interger" is truly awesome! I now can use the formula "=IF(INT(D2)=D2,"Yes","No")", and then fliter "No".

Comment: That's certainly a much simpler method :). Glad you got it figured out!